# Как выполнить js код введенный через input?

Tags: javascript, html

Вообщем, у меня есть кнопка и поле для ввода:

```
<input type="text"></input>
<button onclick='someJSfunc'>DO</button>
```

В поле я записую: alert('hello world');

Как получить этот alert через функцию "someJSfunc"?

Comment: https://learn.javascript.ru/eval

Comment: опасно так делать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Только в учебных целя, такой подход является очень опасным

> НИКОГДА НЕ СТОИТ ТАК ДЕЛАТЬ

```
// способ #1
eval('alert("Hello")');
// способ #2
const func = new Function('alert("Hello")');
func();
// способ #3
setTimeout('alert("Hello")', 0);
```